# find and replace in in file or string in bash

Tags: bash, replace, find

I have this file `httpd.conf` which I want to find the `EnableSendfile` and not the lines that contains that string but the line is starting with an "#" (not the commented lines) if found I want to reset its value to off.

I have tried to come up with this. (I am a newbie in bash language)
but it is not working.

**I want to use the variables in my search and replace command, since I am going to do it later on with array items to loop over keys and their values, therefore I need to use variables instead of plain string.**

Thanks for the help, in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
SEARCH="EnableSendfile"
FILEPATH="/root/scripts/httpd.conf"
REPLACE="off"

if grep -Fq $SEARCH $FILEPATH
then
    line_string=`sed -n '/^EnableSendfile/p' $FILEPATH`
    result_string="${line_string/(^[^#]\w*)(?:\s(\w+))?$/$REPLACE}"
    echo $result_string
else
    echo "not found" 
fi
```

```
#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on
#EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed 's/^EnableSendfile on/EnableSendfile off/'
```

The `^` special character matches at the beginning of lines, so the command won't change lines starting with a `#`.

Comment: hhow can i use the variables with the sed, sinc i am going to do it later on with array items to loop over keys and their values therefore i need to use variables instead of plain strings

Comment: If the variables never contain special characters, you can use them in double quotes: `"s/^$keyword on/$keyword off/"`. Otherwise, you need a more complicated solution.

Comment: ok .i was able to do it, but apparently it is not saving it is just showing the file on the screen, how to save it or replace the original file with it ?

Comment: @Vagho: Either use redirection `> output`, or, if your version of sed supports it, use the `-i` option.

Comment: i used the -i  option it worked, but even though it is giving me this error grep: on: No such file or directory

Comment: @Vagho: My suggestion uses no `grep`.

Comment: this is the script that i am using,

if grep -Fq $SEARCH $FILEPATH
then
 sed -i "s/^$SEARCH/$REPLACE/" $FILEPATH 
else
 echo "not found" 
fi

i cant send anymore comments here apparently i dont have enough points

Comment: Please, remove your email from here. Also, double quote the variables.